# ARP Spoofing Attack? Highly Suspicious Network Activity Detected in Wireshark

Tags: privacy, wireshark, arp-spoofing

Wireshark detect highly suspicious network activity on my system. As you can see in the attached screen capture, broadcast traffic repeatedly sends weird packet information and suspicious requests, such as:

**[TCP retransmission]
[TCP spurious retransmission]
[TCP fast retransmission] 
443 > 449560 [RST, ACK]
[TCP out-of-order]**

[image]

[image]

In addition to Wireshark, I installed xARP software, and it consistently sends me alerts regarding potential ARP attacks, like:

*"DirectedRequestFilter: targeted request. destination mac of arp request not set to broadcast/invalid address"*

I am new to Wireshark. Could anyone help me to decipher this traffic activity and tell me if it's indication of ARP spoofing attack? And, what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: Neither of the screenshots you posted show any ARP packets...

Comment: This looks rather like so called `lag` e.g. slow networks.